# Find upcoming annual and quarterly interviews

Tags: java

I am writing a management application to replace an existing application.  Depending on certain criteria, people are interviewed either quarterly or annually based on certain criteria.  The date of the interviews are determined by their birthday.  I want a dialog that will display all upcoming interviews, one month in advance for annual interviews and one week in advance for quarterly interviews.

I'd like to ask for a general review, especially since this part started as a "hey, can this be put into the program real quick-like?" kind of request and turned into Frankencode by the time I was done.

The applicable code is `showUpcomingForm()` (called from the main app), `SORDate.java` (customized calendar object), and UpcomingDialog.java.  The code for `UpcomingDialog` isn't shown--it's pretty basic, just a dialog with a table to display results.

`showUpComingForm()`:

```
private static void showUpcomingForm() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    List<Interviewee> upcomingList = new ArrayList<>();

    //go thru entire interviewee list
    Iterator i = intervieweeList.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        try {
            Interviewee o = (Interviewee) i.next();

            //Interviewee has an unsorted hashset of Interview objects containing 0-n
            //Interviews.  Gets the last interview using InterviewComparator
            //(compares database id of interview object). If there are no objects
            //in the set, create a blank object to preventnull pointer error.
            Interview interview = null;
            if(o.getInterviews().size()>0){
                //get latest interview
                interview = (Interview) Collections.max(o.getInterviews(), 
                            new InterviewComparator());
            }else{
                interview = new Interview();
            }
            //create calendar objects
            SORDate nowDate = new SORDate(new Date());

            //if there is not date of birth stored, notify the user and skip.
            if(o.getDateOfBirth()==null ||
                    o.getDateOfBirth().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o.getLastName() 
                        + ", " + o.getFirstName() 
                        + " has no date of birth listed.\nDPS Number: " 
                        + o.getDpsNumber(), "Missing Date of Birth",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                continue;
            }
            //get date of birth and turn it into birthday for this year
            SORDate birthday = new SORDate(sdf.parse(o.getDateOfBirth()));
            birthday.setYear(nowDate.getYear());

            SORDate lastInterview = null;

            //if the interview date string is not null or blank, parse it out.
            //if it is null/blank, use last year's birthday for last interview.
            if (interview.getInterviewDate() != null && 
                    !interview.getInterviewDate().equals("") {
                lastInterview = new SORDate(sdf.parse(interview.getInterviewDate()));
            }else {
                lastInterview = birthday.getCloneAddMonth(-12);
            }

            // continue only if interview is still available ("active")
            if (o.getIsActive()) {

                if (o.getRegistrationObligation().equals("ANNUAL")) {

                    //create date range window
                    SORDate nowMinus = nowDate.getCloneAddMonth(-1);
                    SORDate nowPlus = nowDate.getCloneAddMonth(1);

                    //check to see if interview is in window
                    if (birthday.isBetween(nowDate.getDate(), nowPlus.getDate())) {
                        //check to see if it hasn't already been done
                        if (lastInterview.isBefore(nowMinus.getDate())) {
                            upcomingList.add(o);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (o.getRegistrationObligation().equals("90 DAYS")) {

                    //create a due date and identify which quarter we are currently in
                    SORDate dueDate = birthday.getCloneAddMonth(-12);
                    SORDate prevQuarter = nowDate.getCloneAddMonth(-3);

                    //set due date to this quarter
                    while(dueDate.isBefore(nowDate.getDate())){
                        dueDate.addMonth(3);
                    }

                    //create date range window
                    SORDate nowMinus = nowDate.getCloneAddWeek(-1);
                    SORDate nowPlus = nowDate.getCloneAddWeek(1);

                    //check to see if we're in the window
                    if(dueDate.isBetween(nowMinus.getDate(), nowPlus.getDate())){
                        upcomingList.add(o);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(SOR2Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    //sort the list by birthdays
    Collections.sort(upcomingList, new BirthdayComparator());
    //display results
    UpcomingDialog upcomingDialog = UpcomingDialog.getInstance(null, true, upcomingList);
}
```

SORDate.java:

```
public class SORDate {
    GregorianCalendar gc;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    public SORDate(Date d) {
        gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(d);
    }

    public SORDate(GregorianCalendar gcNew) {
        this.gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(gcNew.getTime());
    }

    public SORDate(Calendar c) {
        gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTime(c.getTime());
    }

    public void setYear(int year){
        gc.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    public void addMonth(int numMonths) {
        gc.add(Calendar.MONTH, numMonths);
    }

    public void addWeek(int week){
        gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, week * 7);
    }

    public SORDate getClone(){
        SORDate s = new SORDate(gc.getTime());
        return s;
    }

    public SORDate getCloneAddMonth(int numMonths){
        SORDate s = new SORDate(gc.getTime());
        s.addMonth(numMonths);
        return s;
    }

    public SORDate getCloneAddWeek(int numWeeks){
        SORDate s = new SORDate(gc.getTime());
        s.addWeek(numWeeks);
        return s;
    }

    public boolean isBefore(Date d) {
        long gcTime = gc.getTime().getTime();
        long dTime = d.getTime();
        long tTime = gcTime - dTime;
        if(tTime<0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAfter(Date d) {
        long gcTime = gc.getTime().getTime();
        long dTime = d.getTime();
        long tTime = gcTime-dTime;
        if(tTime>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (d1.before(d2)) {
            if ((this.isAfter(d1) || this.equals(d1)) 
                    && (this.isBefore(d2) || this.equals(d2))) {
                returnValue = true;
            }
        } else if (d2.before(d1)) {
            if ((this.isAfter(d2) || this.equals(d2))
                    && (this.isBefore(d1) || this.equals(d1))) {
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return gc.getTime();
    }

    public boolean equals(Date d){
        boolean returnValue = false;
        GregorianCalendar gc2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc2.setTime(d);

        if(gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==gc2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                && gc.get(Calendar.MONTH)==gc2.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                && gc.get(Calendar.YEAR)==gc2.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
            returnValue = true;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return sdf.format(gc.getTime());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## High level stuff:

Break your code into smaller functions. `showUpcomingForm()` is almost 100 lines of code. Long methods are harder to read and because they are doing many operations. Each method should be doing one things and delegating chunks of code to other functions.

---

In general, comments should say why you are doing something, not what you are doing. If you use good function names when you break your code into smaller pieces, most of the comments in this code can be removed.

---

Separate your business logic from your UI code. `showUpcomingForm()` displays a message box every time it finds an interviewee without a birthday. This means that you can not test this function in an automated fashion (someone needs to be there to click Ok). Going back to the first point, have one function that produces the collection of interviewees that have upcoming interviews, have one function that finds interviewees that don't have birthdays, then have other functions that actually display this data to a user.

This will also provide a better experience for the user. Say I am using your application because I need to see the next person to interview. Turns out, there are 5 people that don't have birthdays. That is 5 extra clicks I have to make before I get to the view I actually care about. Then tomorrow, I need to open the application again to see who is next. I know none of the birthdays have been updated, but I am still told about every person that was listed yesterday.

---

Define constant variables instead of hard coded values. If the plan changes to do interviews every two years, you have to go looking for all of the `-12`s that exists. However, `-12` might means something else in different code, so a find and replace is not safe. Using a constant means you change it in one spot and everything is correct.

## Detailed stuff:

`showUpcomingForm()` is static, yet uses `intervieweeList` to supply the interviewees. This means you have mutable static state. That can become messy would likely work just as fine as just being state kept in a single instance.

---

You use an iterator to loop over the values in `intervieweeList`. If `intervieweeList` is a list, you can use a foreach loop to clean up the code and remove a cast. If `intervieweeList` is not a `List<Interviewee>`, it should not be named `___List`. In fact, unless you have a number of different collections dealing with interviewees, you can name the variable `interviewees` since the type system will tell you the collection type.

---

Why is the `Interviewee` variable named `o`? Using names that mean something help readability.

---

Assuming `getInterviews()` returns a `List`, you can use `isEmpty()` instead of checking if the size is bigger than zero.

---

Decide on one value that means no date exists. Both `getDateOfBirth()` and `getInterviewDate()` can be `null`, empty string, or a real value. Having to check for `null` and empty string will lead to errors when someone forgets that both are seen as valid "non-values".

---

When a birth date is not know, you stop processing the current interviewee. This should happen before you do the processing to get the value for `interview` and `nowDate`.

---

`getRegistrationObligation()` should probably return an `enum` instead of a `String`. `showUpcomingForm()` only expects one of two values, yet you are using a type that can have infinity many values. Switching on an `enum` will also make it clearer that an valid value is not being handled (via a compiler warning).

---

`UpcomingDialog.getInstance()` returns an instance of the dialog and you store it in a variable, but do nothing with it. `showUpcomingForm()` implies that the dialog should be shown. That means `UpcomingDialog.getInstance()` is going more than just getting an instance, it is also displaying the UI component.

## SORDate:

`gc` and `sdf` are accessible by any code in the same package. I don't think you want these to be exposed to other code. These could also be set to `final` since that class never assigns new values to the variables outside of the constructors. The variable names are excessively abbreviated.

---

The constructor that takes a `GregorianCalendar` uses both `this.gc` and `gc`. The argument name does not conflict with the instance variables, so there is no reason to use `this.`. If you do want to use it, you should be consistent.

---

`getClone()` does not need to create a local variable if you are just going to return that variable on the next line.

---

`isBefore()` and `isAfter()` are doing the same things and only differ basted on the if clause. You should move the repeated code into a private method and have the public methods use the private method. `isBetween()` is doing a similar thing with both of its if clauses.

Your if statement just return hard coded boolean values. Instead you can just return the boolean expression in the if clause.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance,

- `o` is a terrible variable name
- `getIsActive` boolean properties typically don't use `get`. I know some source code generators will throw it on there and that is probably what happened in this case.

## Encapsulation:

**Validation**

```
if(o.getDateOfBirth()==null ||
   o.getDateOfBirth().equals(""))

if (interview.getInterviewDate() != null && 
   !interview.getInterviewDate().equals(""))
```

Move it into the respective classes

- `if(individual.hasDateOfBirth())`
- `if(interview.hasDate())`

Similarly, interview intialization would read much better as:

```
Interview interview = individual.hasInterview() ? individual.lastInterview() : new Interview();
```

The `= null` goes away in addition to allowing the `lastInterview` method to assume the responsibility of determining the "last" interview.

---

**Maintainability**

`o.getRegistrationObligation().equals("ANNUAL")` and `o.getRegistrationObligation().equals("90 DAYS")` sway me toward declaring an `Enum`. As the usages of `.equals("Some String")` propagate, so to do the number of places you would have to fix it if the value were to ever change. `Enum` encapsulates that value and provides a single point of value remediation (to a certain degree).

**String Building**

Beyond a couple `+` concatenation usages, I like to switch to `String.format`.

```
 String.format("%s, %s has no date of birth listed.\nDPS Number: %s",       
               o.getLastName(),  
               o.getFirstName() 
               o.getDpsNumber()) //assuming this is a String
```

This would also allow for placement of the resource (the String) into a `ResourceBundle` if that particular error message were to ever need to be reused elsewhere. In addition, the usage of a bundle encapsulates all non-variable based String resources to one place.